# Consuming rest works with curl but does not work when I am usiing RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest

I have an issue with `RestTemplate`, I want to consume  https://swapi.co/api/

It works when I am using Curl:

`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET`

But when I am trying to use `RestTemplate` it doesn't work.

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);


    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://swapi.co/api/", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    Root root = new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody(), Root.class);
    System.out.println(root);
```

As you can see I set Accept and ContentType like in curl command. What am I doing wrong, all time I am receiving 403 Forbidden Status? 
I am using spring boot with spring security, but I disable csrf mode.

Comment: your url says http, but what you shared is https ?? any thing I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the response shows that the request goes through Cloudflare, and that the response contains the following error:

> The owner of this website (swapi.co) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (3a4c8846af5169b2-ua21).

So you can cheat and add an accepted User-Agent header. For example:

```
headers.add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0");
```

You should contact the owner/maintainer/developer of swapi to add a section about that limitation in the documentation, because it's far from being obvious, and should definitely be documented.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `restTemplate.getForObject("http://swapi.co/api/", String.class);` (Returns a string).
It is much more straightforward and self-explanatory.

The 403 you are getting must be something related to your headers, most likely the line that says `headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))`

Comment: I was using a getForObject method, still, I get the same error. What can be wrong with this set.Accept?  It should accept Jsons.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url it says  https://swapi.co/api/ but above code points to HTTP.

```
HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://swapi.co/api/", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```